# I get a MissingSchema error within my python file that is trying to read a local JSON file

Tags: python, json, django

**This is the error I get when I try to load my indexes.html page:**

> MissingSchema at /indexes/
>       Invalid URL "<_io.TextIOWrapper name='tableInfo.json' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>": No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant
>   http://<_io.TextIOWrapper name='tableInfo.json' mode='r'
>   encoding='cp1252'>?

**I am not sure why this is happening, I am trying to read from a local JSON file and display it in a table**

**This is my views.py code:**

```
def indexes(request):
            with open('tableInfo.json') as json_file:
                if request.POST:
                    form = Sea(request.POST)
                    po = request.POST.get('poNo')
                    dc = request.POST.get('dcNo')
                    vendor = request.POST.get('vendor')
                    order_date = request.POST.get('order_date')
                    delivery_date = request.POST.get('delivery_date')
                    payload = {}
                    if len(po) > 8:
                        payload['poNo'] = po
                    if "DC" in dc:
                        payload['dcNo'] = dc
                    if len(vendor) > 8:
                        payload['vendorNo'] = vendor
                    if len(order_date) > 6:
                        payload['orderDate'] = order_date
                    if len(delivery_date) > 6:
                        payload['deliveryDate'] = delivery_date
                    data = json.loads((requests.get(json_file, payload)).content)
                    if data['returnCode'] == 0:
                        resultList = data['resultList']
                    else:
                        resultList = []

                else:
                    form = Sea()
                    resultList = []
                context = {
                    'data': resultList,
                    'form': form
                }
                return render(request, 'users/indexes.html', context)
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to StackOverflow aka. "SO"
Please see the help section as this will guide you in getting more support from us in the community.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/
Best wishes on your endeavors! Cheers!

Comment: maybe you should open JSON file inside `if request.POST:` when you need it.

Comment: `requests.get()` needs url, not opened file - `json_file`. Maybe you have to read url from `json_file`

Comment: I'm sure `requests` isn't a suitable package in this case.

Comment: if you need to read from local file then you don't need `requests.get()` but `data = json.loads(json_file.read())`

Comment: @furas I did data = json.loads( json_file.read() ) and tried data = json.loads( json_file.read() ) but i get this error - " JSONDecodeError at /indexes/
Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read from local file you need

```
data = json.loads( json_file.read() )
```

or using `load()` (without "**s**" at the end)

```
data = json.load( json_file )
```

You don't need `requests.get()` which makes problem.

Comment: I did data = json.loads( json_file.read() ) and tried data = json.loads( json_file.read() ) but i get this error - " JSONDecodeError at /indexes/
Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) "

Comment: this error means your file 'tableInfo.json' is empty and there is nothing to read. Check if you have correct JSON data in this file.

Comment: Yep, I figured it out silly me the path to the JSON file was wrong. Thank you for the help!